# Prevent "ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT" from prompting automatically to change default SMS app

Tags: android, sms, default, android-4.4-kitkat, smsmanager

When setting the permissions and Intent-filters needed to be the default SMS app the app prompts you automatically to be the default SMS app at some point. is it possible to prevent it?
I know that there is a method for calling the ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT intent to deliberately call it at any point and I want to use it to call the action only in a specific time in some part of my code that I choose.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had this call somewhere inside my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This is what triggered the call at first time... It should only be used at the part of the code where we want to explicitly trigger it.